# I need to disable advanced table options

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to disable the advanced options of the table, cells and rows and I am applying the code according to the documentation but I am not getting results.
my code is as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mensaje',
    height: 520,
    language: 'es_MX',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['table', 'lists'],
    toolbar: [
    { name: 'history', items: [ 'undo', 'redo' ] },
    { name: 'formatting', items: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'underline' ] },
    { name: 'alignment', items: [ 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'alignjustify' ] },
    { name: 'listas', items: [ 'bullist', 'numlist'] },
    { name: 'tablas', items: [ 'table' ] }
    
    ],
    table_advtab: false,
    table_cell_advtab: false,
    table_row_advtab: false
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Those options seem to work when I load your configuration into a TinyMCE Fiddle:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/htiaab

What is different in your environment?

Comment: what I need is to disable the advanced properties of the cells, rows and table, I use the options as it is in the official page but it doesn't work.
table_advtab: false,
    table_cell_advtab: false,
    table_row_advtab: false